# Tomcat Access log get a 403 request, but RequestDumperFilter can't see the details of this 403 request

Tags: tomcat

On tomcat 9.0.31, I just configure the AccessLogValve to log all the requests in tomcat,

```
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

in the meanwhile, also configure the RequestDumperFilter in the tomcat/conf/web.xml and logging.properties to see the details as the official documents,

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>rootrequestdumper</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rootrequestdumper</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

```
handlers = 1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler,

1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = request-dumper.
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = \
  1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

**in request-dumper log files, I can see all the requests include those with return code like 404,200. Except 403!!!**
For example, in localhost_access_log.2021-06-21.txt

```
10.240.220.201 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:41:48 +0000] "POST /test/api/case/test201 HTTP/1.1" 403 716
10.240.221.201 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:41:53 +0000] "-" 400 -
10.240.221.175 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:41:56 +0000] "-" 400 -
10.240.221.201 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:42:43 +0000] "-" 400 -
10.240.221.175 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:42:46 +0000] "-" 400 -
10.240.221.175 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:37:06 +0000] "-" 400 -
10.240.221.201 - - [21/Jun/2021:03:37:10 +0000] "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 404 728
```

but in requestDumper filter log files,there's only the 404 request and response:

```
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10 START TIME        =21-Jun-2021 03:37:10
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         requestURI=/actuator/health
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10           authType=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10  characterEncoding=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10      contentLength=-1
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10        contentType=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10        contextPath=
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=host=XXXX
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=accept=*/*
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=accept-encoding=gzip
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=x-forwarded-port=443
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=x-forwarded-proto=https
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=connection=keep-alive
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             locale=en_US
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             method=GET
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10           pathInfo=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10           protocol=HTTP/1.1
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10        queryString=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         remoteAddr=  
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         remoteHost=
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         remoteUser=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10 requestedSessionId=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             scheme=https
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         serverName=
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         serverPort=443
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10        servletPath=/actuator/health
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10           isSecure=true
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10           authType=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10        contentType=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=Cache-Control=no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=Pragma=no-cache
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             header=X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
......
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10         remoteUser=null
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10             status=404
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10 END TIME          =21-Jun-2021 03:37:10
https-jsse-nio-16748-exec-10 ===============================================================
```

Anyone has idea about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some requests never reach your application.

A request must pass through every [`Valve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) before being passed to the [`FilterChain`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/filterchain). After the `doFilter` method of `FilterChain` has been executed, the control returns to the valves in reverse order. The sequence of valves might look like this:

1. `StandardEngineValve` - chooses the host,
2. `AccessLogValve` - logs the request (on the return path),
3. `ErrorReportValve` - writes the error message,
4. `StandardHostValve` - chooses the application,
5. `BasicAuthenticator` - authenticates the user if needed,
6. `StandardContextValve` - chooses the servlet
7. `StandardWrapperValve` - calls the `FilterChain`

Some errors never reach 7:

- A `400 Bad Request` (e.g. the URL contains forbidden characters), never goes past 4.
- If authentication is required and it fails (`401 Unauthorized` and `403 Forbidden`), the request stops at 5 and returns to 4. If you defined some custom `<error-page>`s, the `StandardHostValve` forwards the request again to the application and can be caught by a filter, otherwise control passes to 3.

To answer your concrete case: in the `web.xml` descriptor

- add a custom handler for `403` errors,
- add a new `<filter-mapping>` to be executed, when the [`DispatcherType`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/dispatchertype) of the request is `ERROR`.

For example you can add something like this:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>rootrequestdumper</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<error-page>
     <error-code>403</error-code>
     <location>/WEB-INF/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
     <error-code>401</error-code>
     <location>/WEB-INF/401.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and create two JSP pages `/WEB-INF/401.jsp` and `/WEB-INF/403.jsp` for the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very appreciate. While I add <error-page> into web.xml as you said, seems it doesn't work. And I found there may be a problem in your answer that "If authentication is required and it fails (401 Unauthorized and 403 Forbidden), the request stops at 5 and returns to 4.", because sometimes I get the 403 due to missing csrf token, it's checked by CSRF filter, so it must be handled by my app instead of tomcat valve, which means in your steps, it can reach step 7. And I debug it, it just goes through all the valves and filterChain, please check for the stack below.

Comment: ```
Daemon Thread  (Suspended (breakpoint at line 90 in CsrfFilter))  
 CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain)
 ......
 ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)
 StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) 
 StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response)
 NonLoginAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) 
 StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response)
 ......
 StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response)
 CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response)
 .......
 TaskThread(Thread).run()
```

Comment: I forgot to add a filter mapping for the `ERROR` dispatcher type. I corrected it in the answer. And yes, you are right: the `Authenticator` valve is not the only source of `403` and `401` errors, you can also generate them in your application or one of the filters.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz not all of the 7 valves you list are listed in the [tomcat documentation page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) you link to. I can only see `BasicAuthenticator `. Where can i find the documentation page of `StandardContextValve ` for example? When i google it I can only find the docs for the `StandardContext` class

Comment: I am afraid that the `Standard*` valves are documented [only in source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/tree/main/java/org/apache/catalina/core). They usually just have some logic to route the request to the appropriate container. The remaining 3 are documented in the [configuration reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html).